# What’s the difference between “line” and “row”?

Tags: meaning, word-choice, differences, ambiguity

I’m not exactly sure under which circumstances is *line* or *row* the more suitable term.

In Portuguese, they both translate to the same word *linha*, which can be used for both a drawing line or for an item in a table.

Comment: A _line_ is a connected plane figure. A _row_ is a series of individual instances lying on the same line, and defining it. Thus, a _row_ of soldiers at attention can be spoken of as a _line_ of soldiers. But the graph of x = y is a diagonal line, not a row.

Comment: Is there a distinct term (in Portuguese) for the english noun **file** meaning *a line of people or things one behind another*, as in single-file?

Comment: Altho' *single-file* is used and would be understood in BrE, I'm not aware that we use the word "file" on its own in that kind of sense.

Comment: @TrevorD Think of the term “rank and file” as applied to the military.

Comment: @tchrist I certainly know the expression, but I'd never given even a moment's thought to the meaning of "rank and file"!

Comment: An "item" in a table is not a "row" and surely, not a "line": it's a data element. Tables have "rows" of "items".  "Gosto de plantar narcisos em **filas** (or: **fileiras**) retas. --> *I like to plant straight rows of daffodils.* http://www.wordreference.com/enpt/row

Answer (score 15):

There *is* substantial overlap in meaning, and if you use one where the other would've been more appropriate, native speakers will still understand what you meant; so don't worry about it too much.

For your purposes, I think the most important distinction is that **row** can only be used to refer to an arrangement of *discrete items*.  For instance, in the sentence "He drew a line between the two points on the map", **line** cannot be replaced by **row**.

I can't presently think of an example where I'd say you *can't* go the other way -- replacing **row** with **line** -- but there certainly are cases where it would be odd.  For instance, we normally always speak of a table of numbers having **rows** (which are always horizontal) and **columns** (which are always vertical).  If you referred to a **line** of a table, that would be peculiar, but not wrong, and I think would be understood as unambiguously horizontal (by analogy with **lines** of text on a page, which are always horizontal ... well, as long as you're not talking about one of the East Asian languages that can be written vertically, anyway).

Comment: I often see Line used for a set of item details on an order for example.

Comment: A row of houses would very rarely be referred to as a line of houses. There is a quasi-discrete property if we're talking about a terrace.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth The reason in the case of houses or cars is different from what we are dealing with here, the difference between *line* and *row*.

Answer (score 3):

This Question initially looks very simple, but produces considerable subtlety and no absolute conclusion.

My research today suggests that ***row*** *always* suggests some sense of *horizontality* or *laterality*, from the perspective of some *imaginable* point of observation. It seems that ***line*** at least *has available* (to UK ears, anyway) a *possible* contrasting sense of *hierarchy* or *straight-ahead-ness*... although *line* is not *at all* limited to being used that way.  It is more versatile, but for the same reason also more delicate.

To speak of a vertical row would seem somehow perverse.  It would seem far more meaningful to speak of arranging things in a vertical line—to distinguish *this* line from *some other* possible line in a different orientation.  (It might seem even more normal to speak of *columns*, but that is outside the scope of this Question.)

Most generally, ***line*** seems in some sense to indicate the existence of some kind of *direction*, in any context, i.e. it suggests *variable* vector properties.

***Row*** always seems oddly more specialised (for such an apparently unassuming, everyday term), and although it does imply direction in the sense of left-to-right-ness, this seems to be *absolutely constant* and in fact simply a *logical consequence* of its *denying* any relevant sense of verticality.  *All* rows have that property, however, so the things that *importantly* distinguish one row from any other are its constituents and its (perhaps fluctuating) number, and perhaps (if it is otherwise similar) its position.

***Line***, however, also seems to be importantly about *direction*.

A given ***line*** *might* be conceived-of (or in fact defined) as having a start and finish indicating real or conceptual travel towards a goal or an ideal, whether in discrete steps or continuously.

We have (at least in the UK) organisational *reporting lines*, which have *direction* in quantum steps from junior to senior.  A racing driver takes a particular *line* from the start of a curve until its end. A ***line*** may have a number of discrete elements arranged to suggest direction (in one dimension, logically speaking, *even though in empirical space it can curve*), or may indicate a single, continuous path.

A ***row*** seems always to imply *more than two* elements, in some sense closely comparable to each other and arranged such that they can notionally be observed simultaneously *without* internal hierarchy.  These, too, will be arranged one-dimensionally in the sense that each has a definable and distinguishable place in a sequence, regardless of any real-space curve (e.g. the back *row* of seats in a circular arena is still logically a one-dimensional array, from some arbitrary seat #1 to #however-many).

The differing *scopes* are perhaps economically indicated by usages that seem particularly common in the military.  It seems likely that a *row* of anything would indicate things in some sense side-by-side, under any circumstances; but the completely transparent and painless usages ‘line abreast’ and ‘line astern’ are also entirely clear, e.g. ([oxforddictionaries.com](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/line)):

> **line abreast**
>
> Nautical A formation in which a number of ships travel side by side.
>
> [...]
>
> **line astern**
>
> A formation in which a number of aircraft or ships follow one another
>   in a line.

When *line* and *row* do contrast, the *possible* distinction equates to that between *rank* and *file*, but is much less hard and fast.  *Row* always seems to mean something very like *rank*.  Line *can* mean exactly the same thing, but *can* also be used to suggest ‘not-row’, so that in certain contexts it might (by elimination) mean *file*.  A row of things conveys the sense of them being beside each other.  A *contrasting* line of things would be conceived-of as if the relevant thing about it is that you can start at the beginning of them and go forward (not sideways) to the end.  Even that distinction needs unpacking, though (below).

As far as I am aware *a row of people* would always be thought-of as being positioned side-by side, i.e. in a sense arranged ‘horizontally’.  They might be sequenced in strict order of age, height or even seniority, but even then the term ‘row’ *emphasises* the more salient fact that (whether or not this is literally, physically possible) one might at least theoretically step back and view them all equally, on a level.

Likewise, a row of houses:  while other considerations (e.g. street numbering, or position on a steep hill) might connote some kind of hierarchical progression, describing them as a ‘row’ conceptualises them as being equal units, side-by-side.

By contrast, one pursues a line of thought as if proceeding directly ahead, eschewing any lateral considerations or distractions.

To be sure, in walking down a street one might reasonably say that one is proceeding along a row of houses, with some connotation of starting and finishing, and thus of achieving (from one’s personal perspective) a more ideal state; but the term ‘row’ suggests that one is nevertheless moving along a sequence of essentially equal units.

Similarly, if you are inspecting your staff you might organise them into a long *row* and then proceed along the *line*.  In that case the *row* indicates that the staff are positioned equally *with regard to each other* (perhaps in this context they all have the identical property of being *subordinate to you*), while the *line* indicates *your* perspective of this arrangement of people having a purposeful start and finish.

Another use of ‘line’ is synonymous with ‘queue’, and I can’t currently imagine ‘row’ being used in that sense.  There is a goal, and you start far away from it, and *proceed ahead* towards it.  Your situation is *worse* than that of those ahead of you, *better* than that of those behind, and bit by bit comes closer to the target or ideal.  This sense of ‘line’ seems to be more commonly an American usage, but it would still be perfectly meaningful in the UK to say, ‘People have been queueing since midnight, and the line stretches around the block.’

The terms can overlap again, though, in technical areas.  In tables or databases it is common to speak of rows and columns, with an emphatic horizontal/vertical contrast in those terms:  a row is *implicitly* horizontal, and cannot be mistaken for a column.  It is also perfectly intelligible, however, to speak of ‘lines in tables’.

For example, [one basic educational resource](http://www.eduweb.vic.gov.au/edulibrary/public/teachlearn/student/mathscontinuum/ScaleConversions.pdf) provided by the Australian government comes with the single, simple instruction, *Fill in the missing values for each line in the table . The first row has been done for you.*

One *might* argue that this is sloppy usage for the general public, but the Prentice Hall imprint Que is generally authoritative on IT matters, and *[Microsoft Office 2007 in Depth](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Microsoft-Office-2007-In-Depth/dp/0273721593)* (which one would think should be acceptably proper) gives us, ‘You can also adjust *each line in the table* by letting the mouse pointer hover until it turns into a parallel line pointer.’ (p718)

Similarly with databases...  Although in many purist design contexts we might talk about *records*, rather than *rows*, plenty of technicians also use the term *lines*.  The domain and hosting people WebNet77, for example, [advise us in their FAQ](http://software77.net/faq.html) that, ‘*Each line in the database* represents a range of IPs numbers (known as a block) representing many hundreds, thousands or even hundreds of thousand IP numbers.’

Overall, then, the meaning of *row* generally seems pretty clear, along with certain conceptual, logical or philosophical implications.  The word *line* does *not* share those specific implications, but it comes with its own such that it *can* take on many meanings (including that of *row*)—but for the same reason it can require more specific qualification.

As a slightly baffled footnote...  For the most part it seems much more intuitive to imagine an infinitely-long *line* of things than an infinitely-long *row*.  The latter can still work usefully, though, e.g. the number of possible positions on the tape of a [Turing Machine](http://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/projects/raspberrypi/tutorials/turing-machine/one.html), or the rooms in Hilbert’s [Grand Hotel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert%27s_paradox_of_the_Grand_Hotel) if they are arranged (as they might as well be) in a single horizontal sequence.

Answer (score 1):

If you were talking about a group of people queued for service (such as at a ticket window), you'd normally say a *line* of people. But, once seated inside the stadium or auditorium, they become a *row* of people.

It's similar with cars: on the highway at rush hour, it's a *line* of cars, but, in the parking lot, it's a *row* of cars.

One distinction seems to be that, if the objects are end-to-end, it's more likely to be a *line*, while if they are side-by-side, it's more likely to be a *row*. That may be a decent guideline to start with, but I'd caution against using it as a hard-and-fast rule. For one, it would be hard to apply that standard to, say, trees. In the case of trees, though, I think the wording might depend on the perspective of the onlooker: if the trees were spread across the landscape, they would form a *row* of trees, while, if they stood one behind another off into distance, that might be a *line* of trees (as in *a tree-lined street*).

Comment: Interestingly, soldiers may stand in a line, but they march in a column.   Well, if they’re part of the rank and file, that is.

Comment: I guess they're probably in *columns* between there may be mutiple columns marching side by side. When they're *standing in line* are they facing the back of the adjacent soldier (in marching position), or are they facing sideways (shoulder to shoulder) in what I would call a *row*?

Comment: Where J.R.'s answer has "line" in the first two paragraphs, we would probably use "queue" in the UK.

Comment: @TrevorD We would use "queue" for people waiting for service but we wouldn't for people walking in single file or for cars parked at the side of the road. The orientation of the elements of the line or row, however, is consistent. We do sometimes refer to a 'queue' of vehicles but only when stationary or moving very slowly because of congestion or traffic signals, "a queue of traffic at the lights" for instance.

Answer (score 0):

Technically, a *line* is a *row* of **contiguous** elements. Furthermore, a line does not ordinarily need to be a straight-line.

A row is always visualized as rectilinear.  A row does not necessarily have to have all its elements touching each other (without a gap).

However, in general English usage, the terms are treated loosely as synonyms.

Comment: I don't think of rows as having to be straight, either. Certainly, "rows" of seats in auditoriums don't have to be straight ... they are often curved so they all face the stage.

Comment: @PeterShor "A row is always visualized as rectilinear." It *need not be* straight in practice. When *think* of a row, you certainly don't *think* of a crooked arrangement.

Answer (score 0):

Referring to physical positions, to be "in a line" is to have objects or items arranged in a vertical fashion, while "in a row" refers to a horizontal lineup

Comment: Actually, the vertical arrangement is a "column".

Comment: Welcome to SE ELU.  Your response might be better posted as a comment than an answer.  Answers often give more thorough or concrete responses, and documentation always helps.